# EditorFor default value from two other field (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multiplication, editorfor

I have problem to solve like in this image [(click to show image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiquC.png)
below. My view:

```
@model CodeSimplified.Models.User
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "User";
}

<h2>User</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <fieldset>

      <legend>User</legend>

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value1)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value1)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value1)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value2)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value2)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value2)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MultiplyValue1Value2)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MultiplyValue1Value2)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MultiplyValue1Value2)
      </div>

      <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </p>

  </fieldset>
}
<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
</div>
```

**Result:**

When I enter the value1 and value2, I would like to value in 
MultiplyValue1Value2 completes automatically as a result of the multiplication Value1 and Value2

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `keyup()` as shown :-

```
$('#Value1,#Value2').on('keyup',function(){
    var val1 = Number($('#Value1').val());
    var val2 = Number($('#Value2').val());
    $('#MultiplyValue1Value2').val(isNaN(val1 * val2) ? 0 :(val1 * val2));
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/15/)

Comment: Don't forget to give jquery reference on your page, [jQuery cdn](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use javascprit to do that, with jQuery you can do this like that

```
$("#Value1, #Value2").on("input",function(){
   var val1 = parseInt($('#Value1').val());
   var val2 = parseInt($('#Value2').val());

   if(!isNaN(val1) && !isNaN(val2))
      $('#MultiplyValue1Value2').val(val1 * val2);
});
```

```js
$("#Value1, #Value2").on("input",function(){
   var val1 = parseInt($('#Value1').val());
   var val2 = parseInt($('#Value2').val());

   if(!isNaN(val1) && !isNaN(val2))
   $('#MultiplyValue1Value2').val(val1 * val2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Value1" type="text"/>
<input id="Value2" type="text"/>
<input id="MultiplyValue1Value2" type="text"/>
```